# What's the difference between spend on and spend in?

Tags: prepositions

Most time I used `spend on` in the case like:
`I spent 5 hours on learning Python everyday.`

But, I happened to see a sentence: `I spent a lot time in researching the problem.` So I am curious about the difference between them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124331/is-there-any-meaning-to-distinguish-spend-in-spend-on

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of [this question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124331/is-there-any-meaning-to-distinguish-spend-in-spend-on).

Comment: @marcellothearcane although ELL and EL&U are related, they are separate sites, independent of each other. The OP did not cross post because the older ELL post was written by a different user in  2017. I think we could keep this question here, without troubling anyone.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The thing is it was migrated from here, which I assume could happen to this one if the ELL post wasn't there (assuming we still migrate the same sorts of things that we did in 2017). I think I read somewhere that ELL wouldn't appreciate us migrating posts which have a duplicate, so I guess it's a lack-of-research thing. (It would be cool if search also included ELL results - maybe worth a meta post?)

Comment: You could simply delete the preposition and avoid the problem altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions are necessary, of course, but overuse can make writing sound passive and fussy. For example, the U.S. government has a plain language mandate, and when they talk about omitting unnecessary words, they specifically call out prepositions as a potential problem, saying “Watch out for of, to, on, and other prepositions. They often mark phrases you can reduce to one or two words.”

I see both 'in' and 'on' as superfluous in these particular sentences. I'd suggest instead: "I spent 5 hours learning Python everyday." and "I spent a lot of time researching the problem."

Comment: You omitted more prepositions than is correct. Your last sentence should be "I spent a lot **of** time researching the problem.